# At what point does Leah's Journal: Part 2 become available?

Tags: diablo-iii

For some reason, I am unable to find Part 2 of Leah's Journal in *Diablo 3*.

I usually pick up Part 1 before the people inside the inn turn into zombies, and have checked back periodically throughout my first *real* quest (Killing the mothers, etc.) and have had no luck finding it. I *have* noticed, however, that if I wait until after that quest is completed, Part 3 of her journal appears.

**How do I get Part 2 of Leah's Journal?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find Part 2 of Leah's Journal, you need to check her journal after completing the Fallen Star by talking to Captain Rumford, but before entering the Cathedral during the Legacy of Cain.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to talk to Capt Rumford, then Leah, so she's following you. Then you'll find her 2nd Journal on her table.

Comment: The accepted answer already defines the time period when you can find it.  Your answer isn't providing any additional information.

Comment: Actually it does clear up that you need Leah to follow you into the room, otherwise it won't be there.